# Set CLASSPATH for python

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I want to execute a python file called `ex1.py`. The execution works fine, the program does, what it ought to do.

The problem is the following: This file is stored in the folder `/user_name/pythonEx`. So, everytime I want to execute this file I have to write `cd pythonEX` and then `python ex1.py`. I'm wondering whether it's possible to just write `python ex1.py`, meaning skipping the `cd pythonEx` line.

I tried to write to open the ".bashrc" file and write

```
export CLASSPATH=/user_name/pythonEx
```

and save it. I restart the terminal yet an error message appears saying

```
python: can't open file 'ex1.py': [Error 2] No such file or directory
```

Could someone please tell me how to execute a file by just typing in the terminal `python [file-name].py`?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I use PYTHONPATH:

```
PYTHONPATH=/user_name/pythonEx
export PYTHONPATH
python -m ex1
```

CLASSPATH is, as far as I know, a Java path.
PATH is a bash path. So, you can also make ex1.py executable, then you can run

```
PATH=/user_name/pythonEx:$PATH
ex1.py
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you are adding a directory in the root directory to your “CLASSPATH” variable. User directories are located in the /home directory (i.e., the path you would want to add to your PATH is /home/user_name/pythonEX).

Second, you are supposed to add the directory to the PATH variable, not “CLASSPATH” (which I've never heard of, but perhaps it does something). The way to do this is to write (in your .bashrc file): `PATH="$PATH:<the new path>"`. So to add the aforementioned directory to your path, use this line in your .bashrc: `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/pythonEx"`. This should allow you to execute your ex1.py file, if it is located in $HOME/pythonEx, by typing `python ex1.py`.